# What mistake am I making reducing x^2 to x(1*1)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I had a simple question where I was wondering why one could not reduce this expression in the following way.

Take $x^2$. Then, we can reduce it to $x*x$. It appears that you could extract the factor $x$ to yield $x(1*1)$ which becomes $x$. This is clearly incorrect, but *why* is this incorrect, and why can I not reduce it as so?

I assume the correct way to factor such an expression would be to reduce $x*x$ to $(x+x+...+x)$ x-times, then extract the factor $x$ to yield $x(1+1+...+1)$. How come this cannot be done with $(x*x)$?

Thank you.

Comment: " It appears that you could extract the factor x to yield x(1∗1)" No ? $x*x$ and $2*x$ are different things.

Comment: Multiplication does not distribute over multiplication. $a(bc)\neq (ab)(ac)$. On the other hand, you can factor out an $x$ from the first factor and an $x$ from the second factor: $x\cdot x = (x\cdot 1)(x\cdot 1) = xx(1\cdot 1)$, but I don't see why you would want to.

Comment: You can say $x^2=x^{(1+1)}=x^1 \times x^1=x\times x$

Comment: You're thinking about the distributive property of multiplication over addition, which says that $a(b+c) = ab + ac$. You can use that to factor $x+x = x(1+1)$. Notice the thing in parentheses is added, not multiplied!

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication does not distribute over itself. It is not true that $a\cdot(b\cdot{b})=(a\cdot{b})\cdot(a\cdot{b}).$ It is, however, true that multiplication distributes over addition, so it is true that $a\cdot(b+b)=a\cdot{b}+a\cdot{b}.$ There is where your mistake is. You are assuming multiplication distributes over every operation, but it only distributes over addition.

You said **"I assume the correct way to factor such an expression would be to reduce $x\cdot{x}$ to $(x+x+\cdots+x)$ $x$-times,..."** But this is incorrect. Multiplication is not, in general, repeated addition. The concept of writing $x\cdot{y}$ as $y+y+\cdots+y$ $x$ times only makes sense in the specific case that $x$ is a natural number (or $0,$ which I also consider a natural number). It does not make sense when dealing with an expression such as $\pi\cdot\sqrt{2}.$ What does it mean to add $\sqrt{2}$ $\pi$ times? Nothing, it means nothing. It is nonsensical, as a concept. This is why, in abstract mathematics, operations are defined in terms of a set of rules that uniquely identify what those operations are. In the case of multiplication, the defining characteristic of multiplication is typically that it distributes over addition.

Also, notice that if you decide to rewrite $x\cdot{x}$ as $x\cdot(1\cdot1),$ then you get the result that $x\cdot{x}=x$ for every $x,$ which is just not true, because if you let $x=2,$ then this gives you $2=4,$ which, when dealing with real numbers, is most definitely false.

Comment: That makes much more sense now. Thank you for the clarification. I appreciate it!